# ¿Como concatenar los elementos de una lista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy recibiendo la siguiente lista con dos elementos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo de esa lista es el siguiente:

```
public class BatchIdM
{
    public string BatchId { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que busco es unir los elementos de esa lista separandolos por una coma, investigue y trate de hacerlo con un `string.Join` y lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach(var batch in batchIdDiaActual)
{
  string resultado = string.Join(",", batch.BatchId.ToString());
}
```

Pero no logró obtener el siguiente resultado:
`af00be96809348b68c458a2818b05359,3cefc40df70247fe846801190ba44b20`

Lo único que hago es obtener uno por uno y no como el resultado que espero, espero me puedan apoyar en mi error.

Comment: `string.Join(",", batchIdDiaActual.select(a=>BatchId));` (sin usar foreach)

Comment: Como referencia, en ese foreach estás declarando adentro tu variable que quieres concatenar y seteando un valor, por lo cual en cada iteración se "reinicia" la variable y no concatenas nada en realidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien puedes usar el **método Join** tal como te explican en los comentarios, pero también podrías hacerlo tú mismo:

```
int total = batchIdDiaActual.Count();
string resultado = "";

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    resultado = resultado + batchDiaActual.ElementAt(i).BatchId + ",";
}

resultado = resultado.Remove(resultado.Length - 1);
```

Haces un **ciclo for** que recorra cada elemento de la lista y los vaya concatenando separados por una coma. Al salir del **ciclo for** eliminas la coma sobrante.